# Status code for "resource will never be available in this case"

Tags: rest, http, response

I have a REST API dealing with invoices. Now each invoice has a special "fee list" after it gets financed. Although not all are meant to be financed. I have an endpoint which provides information about this fee list for each invoice. So if an invoice has been financed, it returns 200, if invoice has not yet been financed (so the resource is not yet available but will be) I return 202 but what if invoice is not meant to be financed (resource is unavailable and never will be, in this case)?

I thought of using:

2xx - could not find any code that would match the situation

3xx - disagree with "client must take additional action to complete the request"

4xx - disagree with "situations in which the error seems to have been caused by the client"

5xx - disagree with "the server failed to fulfil a request"

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I have an endpoint which provides information about this fee list for each invoice. So if an invoice has been financed, it returns 200, if invoice has not yet been financed (so the resource is not yet available but will be) I return 202 but what if invoice is not meant to be financed (resource is unavailable and never will be, in this case)?

An important thing to understand in REST, is that the metadata (status codes, headers) are describing resources (documents), not domain entities.

Sometimes, this idea is expressed "your resource model is not your domain model".

Your domain specific client is supposed to be looking at the payloads of the responses; the metadata describes the domain agnostic concerns of the hypermedia resource itself, so that generic components (browsers, caches, proxies, spiders) can contribute.

Another way of expressing the same idea: what we're really doing is sending messages back and forth.  The message for the domain specific client belongs in the payload; so that's where you would communicate to the client what's going on with the invoice.  The metadata is used to describe things like "how long should this particular message be cached?"

If I were designing your API, most of the responses would use `200 OK` as the status code; with the occasional `404 Not Found` when it appears that there may be a spelling mistake in the target URI.

(I probably wouldn't use [202 Accepted](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3) as you have described it, as the semantics mean something different -- `202` is much closer to "I understood your request, but its going to take me some time to get the document ready")

Comment: I agree. Every case the OP lists are business cases and so `200` is appropriate unless something goes "wrong" at the resource level.

Comment: I agree with your general point but I have the feeling that the question in this case is slightly different. From what I understand the OP is not asking the status of a resource and then getting "not financed", but is asking for a resource (the fee list) associated with another resource (the invoice), which is not available yet or will never be. E.g. `/invoice/123/fees` could return either `202` (come back later) or `404` (not found, meaning it will never be available).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's important to highlight that [status codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6) are meant to indicate the result of the server's attempt to understand and satisfy the client request.

So, if *resource is unavailable* means that such resource doesn't exist (hence no representation can be found for such resource), then [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) is a quite reasonable choice:

> The `404` (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

From your question, I can understand that *not meant to be financed* doesn't mean that a representation doesn't exist for such resource. So, if the resource exists (and there's a representation for it), then a [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) seems to be just fine:

> The `200` (OK) status code indicates that the request has succeeded.

Comment: I did think of 404 as the first option too but then its description as "error caused by client" does not quite match. It's not client's "fault" invoice is not going to be financed, it's just type of invoice..

Comment: @SimonaChovancová I've added more details to my answer. In summary, from what I can understand, _not meant to be financed_ doesn't mean that a representation doesn't exist for such resource. In this case, `200` is just fine.

Comment: Hm, not meant to be financed means that resource (fee list) does not exist and never will.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4 :

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did
> not find a current representation for the target resource or is not
> willing to disclose that one exists.  A 404 status code does not
> indicate whether this lack of representation is temporary or
> permanent; **the 410 (Gone) status code is preferred over 404 if the
> origin server knows** [...] **that
> the condition is likely to be permanent.**

And also:

> The 410 (Gone) status code indicates that access to the target resource is no longer available at the origin server and that this condition is likely to be permanent.

So, if you have a resource that is something like `/invoice/123/feelist` and that resource will never be available, then the closest you can get is `410` because `404` has no indication as to whether the condition is permanent or not.